# Converting from a non-scalar type "node*" to scalar type "node" requested

Tags: c++, pointers

This line has the error.  I have tried a lot of different edits to try and fix, but I can't seem to get it right.  What I'm implementing is a queue (using a list), and this particular line is a part of the enqueue(int item) operation.

```
node obj = new node (item, <node * pointer>);
```

The constructor is:

```
node(int new_data, node * next_node ){
          data = new_data ;
          next = next_node ;
}
```

I have tried this line:

```
node * ptr = NULL;
node obj = new node (item, ptr);
```

But this still gives the same error.  Since this node will be the last node in the queue it shouldn't point to anything (maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way!?).  Setting a pointer to `NULL` works in sections prior to this code.  A great start would be to explain what the error message actually means, ie Am I passing a "node*" and it is expecting a "node" or vice-versa?  Maybe I'm missing some info on pointers, or stuff to do with the heap.  Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: _basic -- homework --_  Did you mean to install a downvote attractor??

Comment: And please be specific on errors you get! If you don't get them in english, just use some poor translation from google or such (even better reproduce with [ideone](http://ideone.com/) or similar).

Comment: will keep this in mind for future questions.  Thanks for the heads up, I just wanted to let people know that 1) I am not experienced, so advanced solutions would be inappropriate for my level and 2) I've seen others get flack for not mentioning that their question was homework related and it should be pointed out.

Comment: At least you shouldn't mention _'homework'_ in the questions title ;) ...

Comment: @user1920043: Meh, it's subjective. I don't think those people represent the majority or official views of SO. It's more like, if your question wouldn't be posted if it _weren't_ homework, you shouldn't be posting it at all; otherwise, it doesn't bear mentioning at all.

Answer (score 4):

A `new`-expression returns a pointer to the allocated object. So you need:

```
node* obj = new node(item, ptr);
```

That should be fairly obvious from the error message. It's telling you can't convert from a `node*` to a `node`, since you declared `obj` as a `node`. It's not referring to the arguments you are passing.

Of course, you could just not use `new` at all:

```
node obj(item, ptr);
```